# Javascript field validation inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, validation, foreach

I am building a complex registration form with javascript validation.
There are text fields inserted dynamically if the user states that they have children, the number of fields depends on how many children they say they have.

I get the nodes using `const kidDobFields = agesRow.querySelectorAll('input[name^="age"]');`

In my loop, I am first trying to ensure that the field is no empty, and then secondly ensure the date entered is not more than 16 years ago, if all fields are populated and valid then the form can go on to the next tab of questions.

```
if(document.getElementById('hasChildren').checked && numberKids.value != '') {
        kidDobFields.forEach(field => {
            if(field.value == '') {
                error.style.display = "block";
                error.innerHTML = 'Please enter all dates of birth.';
                field.classList.add("is-invalid");
                return;
            } else {
                var today = new Date();
                var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
                var todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
                var todayDate = today.getDate();
            
                var dobParts = field.value.split("/");
                var dtDOB = new Date(dobParts[1] + "/" + dobParts[0] + "/" + dobParts[2]);
                var dobYear = dtDOB.getFullYear();
                var dobMonth = dtDOB.getMonth()+1;
                var dobDate = dtDOB.getDate();
            
                var age = 'valid';
                if(todayYear - dobYear > 16) {
                    var age = 'invalid';
                }
                if(todayYear - dobYear == 16) {
                    if(todayMonth > dobMonth) {
                        var age = 'invalid';
                    }
                    if(todayMonth == dobMonth) {
                        if(todayDate > dobDate) {
                            var age = 'invalid';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(age == 'invalid') {
                    error.style.display = "block";
                    error.innerHTML = 'Please don\'t include children who are aged 16 or over.';
                    field.classList.add("is-invalid");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('tab3').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('tab4').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('formHeading').innerHTML = 'Availability';
        document.getElementById('step3').classList.add("complete");
    }
```

Using the code above, if I use 3 date fields and leave the first empty, the 2nd and 3rd are still validated.

If I put a date over 16 years ago in the first and leave the others empty, the error shows `Please enter all dates of birth.` because the loop continues, rather than stopping after the first and saying that the date is too old.

I know a forEach cannot be broken out of, but I am not sure how best to improve this validation process.

Comment: You don't have to use forEach

Comment: @Dexygen the variable kidDobFields on the forEach is using `querySelectorAll('input[name^="age"]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use every() instead of forEach() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?retiredLocale=uk

I found answer here: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/foreach-break

your code will look like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('hasChildren').checked && numberKids.value != '') {
    kidDobFields.every(field => {
        if(field.value == '') {
            error.style.display = "block";
            error.innerHTML = 'Please enter all dates of birth.';
            field.classList.add("is-invalid");
            return false;
        } else {
            var today = new Date();
            var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
            var todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
            var todayDate = today.getDate();
        
            var dobParts = field.value.split("/");
            var dtDOB = new Date(dobParts[1] + "/" + dobParts[0] + "/" + dobParts[2]);
            var dobYear = dtDOB.getFullYear();
            var dobMonth = dtDOB.getMonth()+1;
            var dobDate = dtDOB.getDate();
        
            var age = 'valid';
            if(todayYear - dobYear > 16) {
                var age = 'invalid';
            }
            if(todayYear - dobYear == 16) {
                if(todayMonth > dobMonth) {
                    var age = 'invalid';
                }
                if(todayMonth == dobMonth) {
                    if(todayDate > dobDate) {
                        var age = 'invalid';
                    }
                }
            }
            if(age == 'invalid') {
                error.style.display = "block";
                error.innerHTML = 'Please don\'t include children who are aged 16 or over.';
                field.classList.add("is-invalid");
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    });
} else {
    document.getElementById('tab3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tab4').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('formHeading').innerHTML = 'Availability';
    document.getElementById('step3').classList.add("complete");
}
```

Comment: i've just tried this but got `undefined is not a function (near '...kidDobFields.every...')` - just to note, the kidDobFields variable is using `querySelectorAll('input[name^="age"]');` if that helps

Comment: I will accept this answer because it is correct, it just didn't work for me at first until I turned my node list in to an array using `const kidDobFieldsArray = Array.apply(null, kidDobFields);`

Comment: The only thing that's not working correctly, is the form going to the next tab after the last field has been validated, depending on where I put it it will either go when the first field is validated or not at all.